# OpenGL 2.0 es Android framebuffer to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'd like to experiment with frambuffers (learning purpose) but i can't make it work. First I tried to write the code myself but I failed so I searched the net.

[I found this code](http://www.cnblogs.com/jayceli/archive/2013/04/08/3008472.html#top)

I made a project from it but did not work (only changed the pics name) it only displayed a rotating cube with colored sides. So I read more about how should I do it, but it seems to me it should work. Everything I try it is like it doesn't use the texture I create.
If someone could point out the problem or show me a working version I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

That is called Render to Texture.  The original Render to Texture article for OpenGL ES on the PowerVR architecture (with working example code), is here:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES